# How to extract and plot autocorrelated random effects in glmmTMB with an irregular time series?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, random-effects-model, glmmtmb

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024987/how-to-plot-random-effects-in-glmmtmb-when-modelling-autocorrelation-of-irregula), but with an additional question on top of it.

In the code below from the reproducible example data question: [glmmTMB with autocorrelation of irregular times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918655/glmmtmb-with-autocorrelation-of-irregular-times?noredirect=1&lq=1), they show how random effects (intercepts) of mixed models without autocorrelation terms can be extracted and plotted.

```
# Make data frame according to example linked above:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(glmmTMB)

df <- structure(list(DayYear = c(234, 220, 234, 231, 243, 229, 228, 
                                 223, 220, 218, 234, 237, 234, 231, 241, 237, 241, 241, 233, 234, 
                                 234, 232, 218, 227, 232, 229, 220, 223, 228, 224), 
                     DateTime =     structure(c(1495477980, 
                      1399590540, 1495479780, 1495225920, 1464631980, 1495052760, 1463324460, 
                      1494525780, 1494256560, 1494088440, 1495471320, 1495730940, 1495476960, 
                      1495225200, 1432919940, 1495725900, 1432924200, 1432918860, 1495384020, 
                      1495479900, 1463848140, 1495298820, 1399420080, 1463253000, 1463692920, 
                     1495037040, 1494275160, 1494510780, 1463348220, 1494597180),
                     class =     c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                     Year = c(2017, 2014, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                              2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2017, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2017, 
                              2016, 2017, 2014, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 
                              2017, 2016, 2017),
                     N = c(2, 2, 7, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 6, 
                     2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
                     -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- (df
        %>% arrange(DateTime)
        %>% group_by(Year)
        %>% mutate(times = lubridate::decimal_date(DateTime) %% 1)
        %>% ungroup()
)

df3 <- (df2
        %>% mutate(YearF = as.factor(Year),
                   times = glmmTMB::numFactor(times))
        %>% select(N, DayYear, YearF, times)
)

# Construct a model without autocorrelation:

mod <- glmmTMB(N ~ DayYear + YearF + 
                (1 | YearF),
                family = nbinom2,
                data = df3)

# extract random intercepts in 2 ways:
glmmTMB::ranef(mod, condVar = T)
broom.mixed::tidy(mod, effects = "ran_vals")

# plot random intercepts
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(mod, type = "re")

# Now fit a covariance structure:

mod2 <- glmmTMB(N ~ DayYear + YearF + 
                ou(times + 0 | YearF),
                family = nbinom2,
                data = df3)

# extract random intercepts in 2 ways:
glmmTMB::ranef(mod2, condVar = T)
broom.mixed::tidy(mod2, effects = "ran_vals")

# plot random intercepts
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(mod2, type = "re")
```

However, in the glmmTMB models that I use, this approach does not work because I have incorporated random effect intercepts with autocorrelation terms into the models. I have an irregular time series, so the autocorrelation is modelled with the `ou(times+0|YearF)` structure where numeric times are encoded in the factor levels of 'times'.

I want to produce a plot for the random intercept of year on the response variable (N) while accounting for autocorrelation. But I am struggling to extract the random effect of year separately from the random effect of year associated with a specific time in the time series. (When I extract the random effects, there is only a random effect associated with each of the 'times' in the time series).

Would it be worth it to specify a separate random effect `(1|YearF)` in my glmmTMB model before specifying the autocorrelation structure `ou(times + 0 | YearF)`? Then the model looks like this:

```
mod3 <- glmmTMB(N ~ DayYear + YearF + (1|YearF)
                ou(times + 0 | YearF),
                family = nbinom2,
                data = df3)
```